# Binance API: OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 405 Method Not Allowed')

Tags: python, macos, proxy, binance-api-client, oserror

I am trying to access Binance Vanilla Futures data by using [this code][1] as a framework to better understand how to get the data. However, when I input my API keys I get an error OSError.

Here is the code:

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:1086',
           'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:1086'}

base_url = "https://vapi.binance.com"
api_key = "8YbN0qDgaPhYQCQjW8v2v3JOWNHoTjOZgLkXsF1MeT3BY4Lu1TzVrPCd3SQRSBuf"
api_secret = ""
headers = {
    'X-MBX-APIKEY': api_key
}

class BinanceException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, status_code, data):
        self.status_code = status_code
        if data:
            self.code = data['code']
            self.msg = data['msg']
        else:
            self.code = None
            self.msg = None
        message = f"{status_code} [{self.code}] {self.msg}"

        super().__init__(message)


path = "/vapi/v1/ping"
url = urljoin(base_url, path)
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
r.text
```

The output for the last ('paragraph' above) should be:

```
'{"code":0,"msg":"success"}'
```

But I get the following error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:174, in HTTPConnection._new_conn(self)
    173 try:
--> 174     conn = connection.create_connection(
    175         (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
    176     )
    178 except SocketTimeout:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py:95, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     94 if err is not None:
---> 95     raise err
     97 raise socket.error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py:85, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     84     sock.bind(source_address)
---> 85 sock.connect(sa)
     86 return sock

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:700, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    699 if is_new_proxy_conn and http_tunnel_required:
--> 700     self._prepare_proxy(conn)
    702 # Make the request on the httplib connection object.

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:994, in HTTPSConnectionPool._prepare_proxy(self, conn)
    992     conn.tls_in_tls_required = True
--> 994 conn.connect()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:358, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
    356 def connect(self):
    357     # Add certificate verification
--> 358     conn = self._new_conn()
    359     hostname = self.host

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:186, in HTTPConnection._new_conn(self)
    185 except SocketError as e:
--> 186     raise NewConnectionError(
    187         self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
    188     )
    190 return conn

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fae0b2805e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:440, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    439 if not chunked:
--> 440     resp = conn.urlopen(
    441         method=request.method,
    442         url=url,
    443         body=request.body,
    444         headers=request.headers,
    445         redirect=False,
    446         assert_same_host=False,
    447         preload_content=False,
    448         decode_content=False,
    449         retries=self.max_retries,
    450         timeout=timeout
    451     )
    453 # Send the request.
    454 else:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:785, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    783     e = ProtocolError("Connection aborted.", e)
--> 785 retries = retries.increment(
    786     method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    787 )
    788 retries.sleep()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py:592, in Retry.increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    591 if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 592     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    594 log.debug("Incremented Retry for (url='%s'): %r", url, new_retry)

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vapi.binance.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /vapi/v1/ping (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fae0b2805e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProxyError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 path = "/vapi/v1/ping"
      2 url = urljoin(base_url, path)
----> 3 r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
      4 r.text

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py:75, in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     64 def get(url, params=None, **kwargs):
     65     r"""Sends a GET request.
     66 
     67     :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
   (...)
     72     :rtype: requests.Response
     73     """
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py:61, in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     57 # By using the 'with' statement we are sure the session is closed, thus we
     58 # avoid leaving sockets open which can trigger a ResourceWarning in some
     59 # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60 with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:529, in Session.request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    524 send_kwargs = {
    525     'timeout': timeout,
    526     'allow_redirects': allow_redirects,
    527 }
    528 send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 529 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    531 return resp

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:645, in Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
    642 start = preferred_clock()
    644 # Send the request
--> 645 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
    648 elapsed = preferred_clock() - start

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:513, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    510     raise RetryError(e, request=request)
    512 if isinstance(e.reason, _ProxyError):
--> 513     raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
    515 if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    516     # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
    517     raise SSLError(e, request=request)

ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vapi.binance.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /vapi/v1/ping (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fae0b2805e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused')))
```

My guess would be that it has something to do with the proxies, however, I am not smart enough to figure it out, therefore I would greatly appreciate your help!